# Javascript Custom Regex: 1 letter + 1 number (dot) 1 number

Tags: regex, node.js

With Node JS how to regex `xy.y` as follows:

```
x = 1 letter [a-z] (lowercase)
y = numbers [0-9]
```

Example:

```
a13.41 //=> true
```

This is not working in Node JS (works on PHP though):

```
/^[a-z][0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+\z/.test(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
[a-z][0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aC4rC3/1)

Answer (score 2):

[`\z`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) is not supported, `$` anchor is used to match the end of a string.

```
/^[a-z][0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+\z/.test('a13.41'); // false
/^[a-z][0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+$/.test('a13.41');  // true
```